# TikZ data visualization (still?) not working properly for external file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I have some troubles using external files for the data visualization library of TikZ. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes, visualize as line]
data [read from file=foo.csv] ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where `foo.csv` is basically just

```
x,y
0,0
1,1
2,2
```

The same problem has been described in [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198323/tikz-data-visualization-fails-to-load-data-from-file) a year ago. Compilation produces the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point     unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `'. The unreadable part was near ''..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 ... scatter ] data [ read from file=foo.dat ];
```

One solution is to replace all commas with spaces in `foo.csv` and to add `separator=\space` to the `data` options. However, this ONLY works if column headlines are specifically named `x` and `y`, despite the pgf manual stating otherwise.

To sum it up: importing data in `\datavisualization` only works for space separated values and only if the columns are named `x` and `y` for me.
Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you consider the provided answer in the linked question?

Comment: I did, but whether I define the headline inside the external file or via options makes no difference. And the neglection of commas as a separator, which wasn't solved in this answer either, is really irritating.

Comment: Actually it works for me. You have to remove the header in the data file. I guess that there is some bug in how the lines of the file header are interpreted.

Comment: You are right, that works! Don't know, what I had tried in the first place. Still, this is weird behavior and apparently unchanged  for years. I try and report this at the sourceforge project.