# How to plot function from a .csv file in Tikz? The .csv file created from the example from Tikz manual is misread (as all y values are 0)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-datavisualization

**Note:** This question is not exactly the same as [TikZ data visualization fails to load data from file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198323/tikz-data-visualization-fails-to-load-data-from-file) because I don't have any error thrown by the code (the log don't display "! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine (...)"). But if I remove all commas in the .csv file (keeping the header) and "explicitly set separator to \space" as in the linked question (here with `data [read from file=dat.csv,separator=\space];`), the graph is correctly displayed.

With (pgfmanual 3.1.9a, page 854):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data {
      x, y
      -1.5, 2.25
      -1, 1
      -.5, .25
      0, 0
      .5, .25
      1, 1
      1.5, 2.25
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image]

as expected.

But if I create a dat.csv file:

```
x, y
-1.5, 2.25
-1, 1
-.5, .25
0, 0
.5, .25
1, 1
1.5, 2.25
```

and use the code (page 858 says: `\datavisualization ... data [read from file=file1.csv] data [read from file=file2.csv];`):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data [read from file=dat.csv];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I obtain (without any error in the log):

[image]

My code editor (BBEdit) for the .csv file says this:

- file type: Comma-separated Values
- file encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
- line ending: Unix (LF)

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Very likely a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198323/47927 which provides a workaround but not an answer as to why this is.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I don't have any error message. But yes, deleting the first line "x,y" from the .csv file and using `data [headline={x, y},read from file=dat.csv];` instead of `data [read from file=dat.csv];` solved the problem. But why? Must the manual be updated?

Comment: The other question is from 2014, so it is hardly a new problem. I don't know how Ti*k*Z reads the file and parses the data. Maybe [file a bug report](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues)?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Done: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1112